# What is OpenSmpp address-range used for?

Tags: smpp, opensmpp

I am building a small client using [OpenSmpp](http://opensmpp.org/) and while reading their code in [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/smpp/client/SMPPSender.java), I stumble upon a strange concept of *address-range*. It's used in the bind process on line 235.

It's apparently different from smpp server address, it's value example is from their [config file](https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp/blob/master/client/smpptest.cfg) on line 32 and shown below. I am totally puzzled by its usage as everything else seems correct for a bind.

```
# The address range this smpp client will serve
addr-ton=1
addr-npi=1
address-range=11*
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned `address-range` field in theory should define SME (mobile handsets) addresses that will be served by this [ESME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Short_Messaging_Entity) (your SMPP application). However, in practice it's mostly configured on [SMSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) side and this field just ignored.

Quite good explanation can be found here:

- [SMPP Address Range and Regular Expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018052537/http://www.activexperts.com/support/xmstoolkit/online/regularexpressions/)